# How to make WebBrowser wait for Javascript?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

In my webbrowser i need to press a button and then type some text.

```
ePlace.InvokeMember("Click");
//NEED TO WAIT HERE
iStake.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("47.56");
```

How can i make my program wait until the button's javascript is done before i type text?
I tried:

```
while(ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    Application.DoEvents();
```

Wasnt helpful :(

Answer (score 1):

Activate the textfield as last operation of the buttonpress event...

Comment: I dont want to rewrite any events, i want to find the way to know whether javascript is still running or not :)

Comment: Are you kidding me? You can only do this with events or callbacks.

Comment: :( nope, i just didnt know. it seems to me so simple and obviously needed that i was sure there is something like "ReadyState" for checking this.

Comment: You need js framework like jQuery or ExtJS to archive this or you have implement by yourself with a sort of callback which would be easiest way to to this. In both frameworks also, btw.

Comment: Great... so now if i want to do a couple of things in a row with one page i need to write a lot of methods or just learn some jQuery =///